# Screenshots of circular watch are square

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm trying to take screenshots of a Moto 360 watch (which is round) but they are coming out as square. For example the following commands will produce this:

```
adb -s localhost:4444 shell screencap -p /sdcard/screenshot.png
adb -s localhost:4444 pull /sdcard/screenshot.png
```

[image]

In addition to adb I know there is the "Take wearable screenshot" menu option in the  Android Wear app but when I select that it says "Screenshot request sent" but nothing else happens after that. There is no ""Wearable screenshot finished. Touch to send." message which I've read is supposed to appear next.

Answer (score 1):

Internally, even round Android Wear devices uses a square frame buffer so what you are seeing is expected. You can manually circle crop the image or many device screenshot generators (and the preview image for watch faces) do this automatically for you.

Comment: But according to this the screenshots are circular: http://www.androidcentral.com/how-take-screenshot-your-android-wear-device    "If you're taking a screenshot of a round watch, like the Moto 360 or G Watch R, you'll notice that watch face shots show the round face with a black border around it"

Comment: From the same article: "while screenshots of the rest of the interface are just square"